# How to clone Joda DateTime?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

What is the best way to clone some `DateTime` object (or assign it's value to another object)?

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

...

DateTime date = new DateTime();
DateTime cloneOfDate = ???
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just use :

```java
cloneOfDate = date;
```

DateTime objects are immutable, you don't need to clone them.

Comment: I just migrated to Java from Delphi, still have some adaptation problems. :)

Comment: And add a ; to the end to satisfy the compiler

Comment: If you were to really want another object instance? For example to not satisfy == equality, then what is simplest clone approach? new DateTime(date) ?